# python numpy matrix row wise operations: columns in each row

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

How can I loop over a matrix and get the number of columns in each row? If I have a matrix, and some elements are NaN (empty) in the matrix, e.g.: [[4,2,9,4],[3,4,8,6],[5,NaN,7,7],[Nan,8,Nan,Nan]], how can I compute the row-wise length?

I have tried:

```
len(matrix) # number of rows
=len(matrix[0]) # number of columns
```

But that gives me the total number.

So I want to get a vector saying the number of columns in each row: [4,4,3,1] e.g.

My idea is to make a loop like this:

```
for i in matrix:
```

And then a loop where it searches. But I'm not sure how to do this

EDIT: I tried @wavy's method and it worked. Can I do like this:

```
# empty list
Final=[]

for i in range(matrix):
    columns=np.isnan(matrix).sum(axis=1)
    result=-columns+matrix.shape[1]
    if result==1:
        Final.append(matrix[i])
        
        
    print(Final)

I also need to put other conditions, when result==2, and when result>2
```

Comment: Do you want to use this on large matrices?

Comment: No I'm trying now with a 3 (columns)x8 (rows) matrix

Comment: In a numpy array all columns have the same length.  `np.nan` doesn't count as "empty". Sounds instead like you want to count the number of non-nan values.  Which is fine, but the description should be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be faster than David Wierichs suggestion:

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.array([[4, 2, 9, 4], [3, 4, 8, 6], [5, np.nan, 7, 7], [np.nan, 8, np.nan, np.nan]])
y = np.isnan(x).sum(axis=1)
result = -y + x.shape[1]
```

Comment: Thank you! Now that I have this, can I then somehow get it to say "if length of that row is 1 (so only where there is 1 number) then the number in the new vector should be that number"?

Comment: Something like this:

`for i in range(matrix):
        columns=np.isnan(matrix).sum(axis=1)
        result=-columns+matrix.shape[1]
        if result==1: # then here it should keep that number in the vector where result is 1
            
        print(result)`

Comment: After having done what I posted there you can try this: ```x[np.isnan(x)] = 0
for i in range(len(result)):
    if result[i] == 1:
        result[i] = np.max(x[i, :])```. 
There's likely a faster way than looping over the `result` array, but I cannot immediately think of it.

Comment: Is it possible somehow I can ask you some more questions in any way?

Comment: I'm online for a bit longer, we can chat here I think: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216320/discuss-numpy-question

Comment: I do not have reputation enough to chat apparently :( Sorry. Thank you anyway for your help. It was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the rows and for each row use the (negated) numpy.isnan method:

```
lengths = [np.sum(~np.isnan(row)) for row in matrix]
```

As this builds up a boolean array in the `np.isnan`, there might be faster approaches.